# How to update the View in SwiftUI after a value in a class has changed

Tags: swiftui

I have the problem that a value that got changed, does not get updated in the View.

The class:

```
class Produkt: ObservableObject {
    var name:String
    var price:Float
    
    init(name:String,price:Float){
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
    }
    
    func increasePrice(){
        self.price = self.price*1.5
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    func create() -> some View {
       Text("Preis: ")
       Text(String(self.price))    
       Spacer()
       Button("Upgrade") {
           self.increasePrice()
           print(self.price) 
       }
```

ContentView:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        @StateObject var kaffee = Produkt(name: "Kaffee",price:1)
       
        kaffee.create()                    
    }
}
```

I tried to use `@StateObject` and `@Published` but I still haven‘t found a way that it works.

Comment: Your `@StateObject` should be defined *outside* the body, as a property on the `View`.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui

Answer (score 0):

As jnpdx has commented, the `StateObject` needs to be created outside of the body.

Also, if you want to see the view get updated when the price changes then the price needs to be published. This is done by tagging it with the attribute `@Published`.

I would suggest not having the model create the view either, in order to avoid interdependency.

The following works:

```swift
class Produkt: ObservableObject {
    let name: String
    @Published var price: Float

    init(name: String, price: Float) {
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
    }

    func increasePrice() {
        price *= 1.5
        #if DEBUG
        print(price)
        #endif
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var kaffee = Produkt(name: "Kaffee", price: 1)

    var body: some View {
        Text("Preis: ")
        Text(String(kaffee.price))
        Spacer()
        Button("Upgrade") {
            kaffee.increasePrice()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`@StateObject` is for doing something asynchronous, so in your case you just need `@State`, e.g.

```
struct Produkt {
    let name: String
    var price: Float

    init(name: String, price: Float) {
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
    }

    mutating func increasePrice() {
        price *= 1.5
        #if DEBUG
        print(price)
        #endif
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var kaffee = Produkt(name: "Kaffee", price: 1)

    var body: some View {
        Text("Preis: ")
        Text(kaffee.price, format: .currency)
        Spacer()
        Button("Upgrade") {
            kaffee.increasePrice()
        }
    }
}
```